# Configure SoapUI to fail the test if the server doesn't require Client Auth

Tags: soapui

I've exposed a service with an https endpoint and I'm trying to test it with SoapUI 5.0.
I would like to configure my SoapUI client to fail the test if the server doesn't require client authentication. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would to not provide the "required" authentication and assert expected outcome.

Create a testsuite that has a teststep that is a happy path test that does not pass any client authentication. Assert on this teststep to fail if it succeeds or pass given your pass criteria.

Comment: I want the client to fail only if the server is configured not to ask for client auth.

Comment: I think the answer is correct. If you make a correct request without required authentication and the response from the server is correct, therefore obviously the server doesn't require the authentication credentials. Add an assert to your testStep which fails if response is ok.